# SQL using less than in to order the result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If there were a table like the follwing:

```
id   title
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
```

I want to know if there is a way of selecting rows in a order by first selecting the rows with id less than 3 ordering them in id descending order, than selecting the rest in id descending order, so in this case, row 2,1,4,3.I was wondering if there was a sql statement something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDERY BY id<'3' id DESC, id DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple expressions in the `order by`:

```
order by id < 3 desc,
         id desc
```

This is close to your expression, but you have an extra `id` in it.

Answer (score 0):

It will do the same like Gordon's answer. But I think this will make more sense for understanding.

```
ORDER BY CASE id < 3 THEN 1, ELSE 0 END DESC,
     id DESC
```